# Why I can not run server.js on localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

So I have a folder with a file server.js, inside server.js there is a code like this:

```
var http = require ('http');
    
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log(req);
    console.log("***********************************");
    
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
    res.write('Hello World');
    res.end();
}).listen(80);
```

also in a folder with this file, I installed node modules and npm and package.json and package-lock.json
but for some reason when I try to run it with node server.json, in doesn't run on port 80 but instead this happens. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynn4o.jpg

How can I fix this? I want to be able to open server.js via chrome, and it should write out hello world

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, **error messages**, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Port 80 is usually privileged and you need extra permissions to bind to that port. Does it work for you if you use sth like port `8080` for example?

Comment: @m90 - I don't think Windows does that. (The screenshot looks Windows-like.)

Comment: If I copy that code into a file on a Windows box (in your image it looks like you're using Windows), stop my usual web server, and run it, it runs just fine. Going to `http://localhost` shows me the "Hello World" in the web page and the logs in the console. If you're doing this on a non-Windows host, as @m90 said, ports < 1024 are likely reserved, but in that case I'd expect you to get an error.